# Form can be sized/dragged to a larger size but cannot be sized/dragged back to a smaller size

Tags: c#, winforms, formborderstyle

I have this simple problem and I have tried searching for answers but came up empty handed.

See, I have this small program that has `FormBorderStyle` set to "Sizeable". My problem is that it can only be sized bigger but I can't drag it back to a smaller size (it simply won't allow me to).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the form's properties and their values?  Should just need what's in the designer file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `GroupBox` with the [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property set was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your forms minimum width and height... likely these are set and preventing you from making it smaller. Set them to 0 and you should be good to go.

Comment: It still got the default 0, 0 MinimumSize. That's the reason why I don't understand why it won't allow me to resize the form to a smaller size.

Comment: Hmmm, what is the form border style set to? does it seem to stop on any items? Could be a binding issue...

Comment: I got it... The Anchor property is preventing it. Thank you for the replies.